# Why is for x in arr seem to evaluate multiple times?

Tags: python

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = []
        set_num = set(nums)
        self.loop = 0
        def dfs(curr):
            self.loop += 1
            print(self.loop, curr, set_num)

            if not set_num:
                result.append(curr.copy())
                self.loop -= 1
                return

            set_num2 = set_num.copy() # <<-- without the copy, wrong solution
            for num in set_num2:
                print(self.loop, 'picking', num)
                set_num.remove(num)
                curr.append(num)
                dfs(curr)
                print(self.loop, 'Adding', num)
                curr.pop()
                set_num.add(num)
            print(self.loop, 'recur end')
            self.loop -= 1
        dfs([])
        return result
```

if `nums = [0,1]` this is the print statement without the copy:

```
1 [] {0, 1}
1 picking 0
2 [0] {1}
2 picking 1
3 [0, 1] set()
2 Adding 1
2 recur end
1 Adding 0
1 picking 1
2 [1] {0}
2 picking 0
3 [1, 0] set()
2 Adding 0
2 picking 0
3 [1, 0] set()
2 Adding 0
2 recur end
1 Adding 1
1 picking 1
2 [1] {0}
2 picking 0
3 [1, 0] set()
2 Adding 0
2 picking 0
3 [1, 0] set()
2 Adding 0
2 recur end
1 Adding 1
1 recur end
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement
Here it is stated that the for loop is evaluated once.

My understanding is that

```
for i in range(len(any_list)):
    any_list.append(1)
```

would terminate since `len(any_list)` is only evaluated in the beginning.

But why does `for num in set_num2` seem to evaluate more than once?
And if it does evaluate itself multiple times, shouldn't the loop go into infinite loop?

What is going on here?

Comment: Remember that Python doesn't copy arrays when assigning to a new variable, so you ended up modifying the very array you were iterating over. Consider using `map` here.

Comment: The expression is evaluated to a single list. That doesn't mean the contents are copied as they exist at that point in time -- rather, that single evaluation result is iterated over as the loop proceeds. If you mutate what the result refers to, then the iterator's returned values will charge as well. Compare to a case where you _replace_ the list with a different one instead of _mutating_ it in place -- the replacement wouldn't be seen.

Comment: See f/e [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python) and the many duplicates thereof for further discussion. Indeed, arguably this is outright a duplicate of that prior question.